# How to I replace certain letters from javascript inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, utf-8

I get out "Å, Ä, Ö" like this "Ã ¥, Ã ¤, Ã ¶" when printing data from an external JSON file. This file has the wrong encoding, but I can not do anything about that file because it is from an API. But, is there a painless way of getting all "1" replaced with "A"? I tried getting a UTF-8 encoded tag in my HTML document. Not helping.

Comment: Make them fix that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regex replace:

```
 wholetext.replace(/1/g,'A')
```